# Can we emit signals of a base class in pyside?

Tags: python-3.x, pyside, signals-slots, super

Is it possible to inherit signals from a base class and in the derived class connect methods to them? If yes, how?

### Working testcase with composition

Instantiates a `MyObject` in a `MyWidget`, and in the widget reacts to a signal emitted by the object.

```
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide.QtCore import QObject, QTimer, Signal
from PySide.QtGui import QLabel

class MyObject(QObject):
    sig = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.alert)
        QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.exit)
    def alert(self):
        self.sig.emit()
    def exit(self):
        print('All done')
        exit(0)

class MyWidget(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.monitor = MyObject(self)
        self.monitor.sig.connect(self.update)
    def update(self):
        print(2)

app = QApplication([])
w = MyWidget()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

It is a small but working example that opens a minimal, empty window, the `self.monitor` object instantiated by the widget emits a timer signal after 3 and 5 seconds. The first prompts the widget to just print a number to the console, the second signal causes the application to quit.

### Failing testcase with inheritance

For inheritance only the widget class is changed to:

```
class MyWidget(MyObject, QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.sig.connect(self.update)
    def update(self):
        print(2)
```

If this is run in the console nothing is printed but a Segmentation Fault happens.
Why? And can this be salvaged?

### Salvaged by replacing `super()`

Interestingly, if both classes are changed to not use `super()`, the example works again:

```
class MyObject(QObject):
    sig = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.alert)
        QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.exit)
    def alert(self):
        self.sig.emit()
    def exit(self):
        print('All done')
        exit(0)

class MyWidget(MyObject, QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        MyObject.__init__(self, parent)
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.sig.connect(self.update)
    def update(self):
        print(2)
```

[Generally I prefer to use `super()`](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), but maybe I need to [reconsider](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/)? I've purposefully linked to two controversial articles about the usage of `super()` in Python. And now would be interested in how to use `super()` properly with pyside, or in explanations why it doesn't work in pyside at all.

**Minor update:**
When using inheritance and `super()` but removing all signal related code the example works in that it does open up the window and does not segfault. So there seems to be some indication that the combination of `super()` initialization and signals causes a problem.

**Minor update2:**
..and when commenting out the `self.sig.connect` the window starts up and only segfaults when the 5-second signal fires to exit the application.

(This is Qt 4.8.4, Pyside 1.1.2 on an Ubuntu 13.04 system with a CPython 3.3.1 interpreter)

Comment: does it crash or exit cleanly?  and I think `sig.connect()` is sufficient as the signal should be a class level not instatiation level attribute.

Comment: @tcaswell: Segfault by my definition is a crash and no clean exit. Signals are always connected between objects. [This doc](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide) is not explicit about it, but lists no alternative. And, thinking about it, it does not make sense to connect signals and slots for classes, because that would imply that all objects of those classes are connected. Instances can be connected and talk to each other, classes are just typedefs in that regard. Types could define a protocol how to talk to each other, but they couldn't actually communicate. Objects do.

Comment: It was not clear that you were getting seg-faults.  There is deep magic being done by the wrapper layer to map the python to the c++ and back.  If you are getting seg-faults you are pushing the c++ layer into a bad state.

Comment: looking at this more carefully, I suspect the problem is that you are getting diamond-diagrams in the c++ layer.  Even though python can cope with it, the `pyside` objects are a thin wrapper around the c++ objects and their instantiation is getting messed up.  my understanding of `super` is that it is like const correctness in c++ in that it works great if you use it _everywhere_ and causes great pain if you only use it sometimes.

Comment: That is, I think if you don't mix in `QLabel` it will work.

Comment: @tcaswell: That is true and a good suggestion. I cannot omit `QLabel` from the consumer's dependency list. For Qt custom widget inheritance is much easier to handle than composition. But I can omit `QObject` from the `MyObject` making it a true mixin. Posted a working code example.

Comment: nifty. glad my rambling was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution - or rather workaround - I could come up with so far that satisfies the criteria (a) inheritance and (b) use of `super()` is to prevent the diamond relationship as inspired by a comment by user tcaswell.

For my use case it is essential to retain the inheritance of any consumer classes (for custom widgets). On the other hand it is guaranteed - currently - that all consuming classes will be derived (indirectly) from `QObject`. Therefore there's no need to derive `MyObject` from `QObject`, though this in fact creates a true abstract MixIn class: It is not usable standalone and has interface requirements to consuming classes. I'm not sure if I like it.

Here's the working code:

```
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide.QtCore import QObject, QTimer, Signal
from PySide.QtGui import QLabel

class MyObject:
    sig = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.alert)
        QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.exit)
    def alert(self):
        self.sig.emit()
    def exit(self):
        print('All done')
        exit(0)

class MyWidget(MyObject, QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.sig.connect(self.update)
    def update(self):
        print(2)


app = QApplication([])

w = MyWidget()
w.show()


app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4):

Qt does not support [multiple inheritance from `QObjects`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first), and the same limitation applies to PySide and PyQt. Although there are sometimes ways to work around this limitation, it is generally a bad idea to attempt to create subclasses with two or more `QObject` base classes.

For the inheritance of signals, using a simple non-`QObject` mixin is probably the best way to go - although I think this solution will only work with PySide; for PyQt4, signals can only be defined on `QObject` subclasses.

**UPDATE**:

This latter restriction was removed in PyQt5: it is now possible to define properties, signals and slots in classes that do not inherit from `QObject`.

Comment: Ah. That's an interesting tidbit of info on PyQt! I'm glad to get this little advantage from pyside.